# Check for sequence in column of Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, series

My DataFrame looks like this:

```
    Category       Date
81    Monate 2020-01-01
88    Monate 2020-01-02
58    Monate 2020-01-03
3     Monate 2020-01-04
23    Monate 2020-01-05
..       ...        ...
134   Wochen 2020-05-24
145     Tage 2020-05-25
147     Tage 2020-05-26
146     Tage 2020-05-27
148     Tage 2020-05-28
```

It is ordered by `Date`. I need to run a check if on each row Monate follows Monate, Wochen follows Wochen and so on. It is allowed that Wochen follows Monate and Tage follows Wochen. I hope it is clear that I mean. Something looks this should cause an error, since the sequence is invalid.

```
    Category       Date
81    Monate 2020-01-01
88    Monate 2020-01-02
58    Tage   2020-01-03
3     Monate 2020-01-04
23    Monate 2020-01-05
..       ...        ...
134   Wochen 2020-05-24
145     Tage 2020-05-25
147     Tage 2020-05-26
146   Wochen 2020-05-27
148     Tage 2020-05-28
```

I could try to write a pretty complicated and probably slow iteration over each row.

```
for row in result_df.iterrows():
    do xyz
```

Is there a better and quicker way to check for an ongoing sequence in a Series or a maybe in a list, dictionary etc.?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you can create a numeric dictionary stating the order and replace the values of the Category column and check if `series.diff` is never negative with `series.all`:

```
def check(dataframe):
    d = {'Monate':1,'Wochen':2,'Tage':3}
    return dataframe['Category'].replace(d).diff().fillna(0).ge(0).all()
```

Test Runs:

```
print(df,'\n\n',f"Valid? : {check(df)}",'\n\n',df1,'\n\n',f"Valid? : {check(df1)}")

 Category        Date
81    Monate  2020-01-01
88    Monate  2020-01-02
58    Monate  2020-01-03
3     Monate  2020-01-04
23    Monate  2020-01-05
134   Wochen  2020-05-24
145     Tage  2020-05-25
147     Tage  2020-05-26
146     Tage  2020-05-27
148     Tage  2020-05-28 

 Valid? : True 

     Category        Date
81    Monate  2020-01-01
88    Monate  2020-01-02
58      Tage  2020-01-03
3     Monate  2020-01-04
23    Monate  2020-01-05
134   Wochen  2020-05-24
145     Tage  2020-05-25
147     Tage  2020-05-26
146   Wochen  2020-05-27
148     Tage  2020-05-28 

 Valid? : False
```